# An example where $R\circ R^{-1}=i_A$ but $R^{-1}\circ R\ne i_A$

Tags: relations

I'm looking for an example where R is a relation from set $A$ to $A$ and 
$R\circ R^{-1}=i_A$  (the composite of $R$ and inverse $R$ is equal to identity relation) 
but  $R^{-1}\circ R\ne i_A$ (the composite of inverse $R$ and $R$ is not equal to identity relation).
For example A={1,2,3} and 1R2, 2R3 and 3R1 (but in this case both ways equals the identity relation).

Comment: $R^{-1}$ is usually a two-sided inverse, I think.  You should probably say you want an example where $R\circ S= id$ but $S\circ R\ne id$

Comment: **Hint:** Consider $R$ to be a surjective (but not injective) map on $A$. Then, it has a right inverse but no left inverse.

Comment: You should define $R^{-1}$.  If $R \subset A \times A$ is a set of ordered pairs is $R^{-1}$ the set of reversed ordered pairs?  If not, what is it?

Answer (score 0):

xRy when xy = 0, a relation over the reals.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be the set of polynomials with real coefficients.  Define $J:A\to A$ by $J(p)=\int_o^x{P(t)dt}$ and define $D:A\to A$ by $D(p)=p'(x).$ Then $D\circ J=id_A$ and $J\circ D \ne id_A$.  You shouldn't have any trouble proving the former, or coming up with a counterexample to demonstrate the latter.

(Well, you shouldn't have any trouble if you've already had a calculus course.  If you haven't, let me know, and I'll explain further.)

Comment: I'm looking for an example over sets (added example). Thanks

Comment: And the set of polynomials isn't a set?